# push item in listfield in django models

Tags: django-models

I have a Django model(CategoryModels) and in it, I have a list field as below:

```
category=['a', 'b'], id_name='test'
```

and I want to push category 'c' to the id_name='test'
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add "c" to category list by using:

```
inst = CategoryModels.objects.get(id_name="test")
inst.category.append("c")
inst.save()
```